# creation of table on SQLiteDatabase fails

Tags: android, sqlite

I am adding a new table on my database with this code:

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + QRCODE_LINK + "(" +
                    "ID" + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "Title" + "text,"
                    + "HISTORY" + " text not null);" );
}
```

However, i am getting an error whenever i'm inserting a data because the table, according  to the logs, does not exist. Did i miss something when i created the table?

Here is the log:

```
10-17 13:56:55.362: ERROR/Database(6791): Error inserting inhistory=1 qr_url=data1
10-17 13:56:55.362: ERROR/Database(6791): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: qrcode_link: , while compiling: INSERT INTO qrcode_link(inhistory, qr_url) VALUES(?, ?);
10-17 13:56:55.362: ERROR/Database(6791):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
10-17 13:56:55.362: ERROR/Database(6791):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
10-17 13:56:55.362: ERROR/Database(6791):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
10-17 13:56:55.362: ERROR/Database(6791):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
10-17 13:56:55.362: ERROR/Database(6791):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1123)
10-17 13:56:55.362: ERROR/Database(6791):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1509)
10-17 13:56:55.362: ERROR/Database(6791):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1382)
```

Comment: Can you provide the source for your SQLiteOpenHelper ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some spacing before telling if it is integer or text.

It's correct in you `History` column, but entry in your `ID` column you actually have `IDINTEGER` and in you `Title` column you have `Titletext`.

```
@Override   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + QRCODE_LINK + "(" +
                    "ID" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "Title" + " text,"
                    + "HISTORY" + " text not null);" ); }
```

Hope this makes sense:)

**EDIT**

Okay Read the code again. You need spacing when creating your Table `"CREATE TABLE " + QRCODE_LINK + "("` and so on.

Actualy as Agriesean said. But without the other corrections you will not have the correct columns.

Answer (score 3):

they didn't have space after Create Table